# Pandas DF FIll NA

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below DF

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "a":["123","123","456","456"],
    "b":["","FHFGH12","asfdas12",""],
    "c":["12-9-23","13-9-23","13-9-23","14-9-23"]
})
```

I want the desired output

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "a":["123","123","456","456"],
    "b":["FHFGH12","FHFGH12","asfdas12","asfdas12"],
    "c":["12-9-23","13-9-23","13-9-23","14-9-23"]
})
```

I want the b column to be filled based on the unique id a.

Comment: `s = data['b'].replace('', pd.NA) ; df['b'] = s.fillna(s.groupby(data['a']).transform('first'))`